# How to generate different CSS bundle with Webpack 5

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, frontend

I have a React project with webpack (own configuration), from which I need to generate different packages with different styles. It would always be the same application, only in each package it generates, it would need a particular css file to end up in the package.
For example, in the repository I would have different css files:

```
- src
  - index.js
  - index.html
  - themes
    - theme1
        theme1.css
    - theme2
        theme2.css
    - theme3 
        theme3.css
```

and when I build it should look like this:  (in "build" folder)

```
- build
     index.html
     main.css // with the styles of theme2, for example
     bundle.js
```

I don't know how to do this with webpack or which plugin, hope you help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get multiple separate CSS by adding multiple entries in your configuration.

Example:

`webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./path/to/your_main.js",
    "css-theme-1": "./path/to/your/theme.css",
    "css-theme-2": "./path/to/your/another-theme.css",
  }
}
```

Also, you can build it into a folder by configuring `filename` properties in `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

Further reading:

- [Webpack Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

Comment: Thanks! is what i was looking for

Comment: Happy to hear that! @foviedo. You can mark my answer as accepted solution then ;)

Comment: If there are any duplicated modules between entry chunks they will be included in both bundles.
It isn't as flexible and can't be used to dynamically split code with the core application logic.

this is from the docs, doesn't seem like a solid method. Just a possible one.